# Jmeter - JUnit Sampler

Tags: junit, jmeter, jmx

I am stuck at this point. I have used JUnit Sampler before successfully many times. But this time I get following error while trying to run simple program.

I have tried different version of jemeter.
I copied the selenium server file to jemeter/lib 
I copied the jar file to lib/junit

I tried their test class and I tried my class

```
2014/11/05 16:27:23 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JUnitSampler: Trying to find constructor with one String parameter returned error: test.BeforeAnnotatedTest.<init>(java.lang.String)**
```

whole stack trace:

```
2014/11/05 16:27:23 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test! 
2014/11/05 16:27:23 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: [] 
2014/11/05 16:27:23 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true,*local*) 
2014/11/05 16:27:23 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group 
2014/11/05 16:27:23 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group. 
2014/11/05 16:27:23 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will stop on error 
2014/11/05 16:27:23 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group number 1 threads 1 ramp-up 1 perThread 1000.0 delayedStart=false 
2014/11/05 16:27:23 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1 
2014/11/05 16:27:23 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started 
2014/11/05 16:27:23 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1 
**2014/11/05 16:27:23 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JUnitSampler: Trying to find constructor with one String parameter returned error: test.BeforeAnnotatedTest.<init>(java.lang.String)** 
2014/11/05 16:27:23 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stop Thread detected by thread: Thread Group 1-1 
2014/11/05 16:27:23 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1 
2014/11/05 16:27:23 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test 
2014/11/05 16:27:23 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false,*local*)
```

Here is my class:

```
package jmeter;

import java.io.File;    
import java.util.Iterator;    
import java.util.Set;    
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;    
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;    
import org.junit.Before;    
import org.junit.BeforeClass;    
import org.junit.Test;    
import org.openqa.selenium.By;    
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;    
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class ShoppingCartTest {

  public  WebDriver driver=null;

  //Initializes/loads  the driver based on type of browser defined in config file
  @Before
  public void initDriver(){
      driver =new FirefoxDriver();
      driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  @Test
  public void verifyAnItemToWishList() throws InterruptedException{
    driver.get("http://www.google.com")     
    System.out.println("done");

  } 
}
```

Comment: A quick fix is to create two constructors in your class, one with no parameter, another with a string parameter, i think there is a bug in JUnitSample.java. Find another time to read the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good and there are no issues there. Make sure that following conditions are met:

1. Your class is packaged into .jar file and dropped into /lib/junit folder of your JMeter installation (or alternatively under location specified by `user.classpath` property)
2. Looking into your `@Before` and `@Test` annotations - you're using JUnit4. In that case you need to tick `Search for JUnit4 annotations` box in your JUnit Request Sampler as below:

[image: JUnit4 annotations]

See [How to Use JUnit With JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-junit-jmeter) guide for comprehensive walkthrough on all aspects of using JUnit in JMeter.

P.S. It may be easier to consider [WebDriver Sampler](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) available via [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/) instead?

Comment: There is no problem to create the Junit Request (detected the Junit 4, classname and Test Method). The error is when running it.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. It got resolved on Downloading fresh instance of Jmeter, installing Selenium/WebDriver Support plugin and Selenium Server Standalone jar. So this error might be just because of not having required Jar in Jmeter Lib folder.

Comment: this should be comment.

Comment: I was searching through Stackoverflow for issue I was facing but answer didn't resolve the issue. I got it resolved with fresh installation, so thought to sign up and post suggestion. Didn't know difference between answer and comment. . Thanks for letting me know difference between them!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, it got resolved with added System.setProperty and i dint add any other constructors (default constructor and any parameter constructor, i had tried with even these 2 constructor even then it was not working, then i added System.setProperty it worked),

For firefox,

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

this resolved my issue.