# JMeter JunitSampler unable to find constructer with string parameter

Tags: java, jmeter, junit4, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I am working on performance testing a command line tool. I already have an integration test written using Junit that tests the entirety of the command line tool and I'd like to reuse it for monitoring performance.

I am using the JUnit Request Sampler but it is unable to start the test because of the error.

`2016/05/18 16:22:36 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JUnitSampler: Trying to find constructor with one String parameter returned error: org.someorg.integration.IntegrationTest.<init>(java.lang.String)`

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26767967/jmeter-junit-sampler) and I don't have a setUp or a tearDown in my tests. Thoughts on what I maybe missing?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I resolved it with two constructors:

- The standard empty one
- A "dummy" one taking a String, calling the other one

Like this:

```
public MyTestClass() {
   // Do nothing
}

public MyTestClass(String test) {
  this();
}
```

JMeter stopped complaining after this. A bit weird, but if it works...
**As a side effect, the test would not run in eclipse anymore**, so I created two versions of the test class:

- One for Eclipse
- One for the JAR for JMeter

Answer (score 0):

As per [How to Use JUnit With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-junit-jmeter) guide:

> **Constructor String Label**
>
> If your JUnit test class has a constructor which accepts a single String, you can set its value with this parameter. If your JUnit test class doesn’t declare such a constructor, the JUnit Sample will try to look for an empty constructor.

So you have 2 options:

1. Your JUnit class should have constructor with 1 [java.lang.String parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)
2. Your JUnit class should have empty constructor

If one of above conditions is met - JMeter will be able to run your class.

See [Providing Constructors for Your Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) guide for explanation of the "constructor" bit.

Comment: I did checkout your blog before I started with this. Unfortunately, an empty constructor still did not work. 

I have created a github repo to demonstrate the same [here](https://github.com/praveenag/jmeter-unit-tests/tree/master)

I still get the error that says, 

`2016/05/19 11:20:53 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JUnitSampler: Trying to find constructor with one String parameter returned error: org.something.MainTest.<init>(java.lang.String) `

Comment: With just one empty constructor it works from command line but not from JMeter UI

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue and after trying many solutions things didn't work. Things started to work after giving unique name to JUnit samplers. I have 100 JUnit samplers and didn't cause any problem after using unique names to sampler.

You don't have to add constructor to your Test class. Giving Unique name to sampler is good enough.